# Can i read the content of a gmail mail?

Tags: java, email

The following code are used to retrieve email from gmail account..This code somehow works for me..I can get the subject and from address but failed to read the content of the mail.
thanks if any one having any solution

```
    import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

/**
* Class reads emails
*
* @author itcuties
*
*/
public class JavaMailReader {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       readEmails(true);
   }

   /**
    * Method reads emails from the IMAP or POP3 server.
    * @param isImap - if true then we are reading messages from the IMAP server, if no then read from the POP3 server.
    */
   private static void readEmails(boolean isImap) {
       // Create all the needed properties - empty!
       Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
       // Create the session
       Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(connectionProperties,null);

       try {
           System.out.print("Connecting to the IMAP server...");
           // Connecting to the server
           // Set the store depending on the parameter flag value
           String storeName = isImap ? "imaps" : "pop3";   
           Store store = session.getStore(storeName);

           // Set the server depending on the parameter flag value
           String server = isImap ? "imap.gmail.com" : "pop3.gmail.com";
           store.connect(server,"coding@gmail.com","P@ssw0rd1");

           System.out.println("done!");

           // Get the Inbox folder
           Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");

           // Set the mode to the read-only mode
           inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

           // Get messages
           Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();

           System.out.println("Reading messages...");

           // Display the messages
           for(Message message:messages) {
               for (Address a: message.getFrom())
                   System.out.println("From:" + a);

               System.out.println("Title: " + message.getSubject());
               System.out.println();
               System.out.println(message.getContent());
               System.out.println("---");
           }

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }

}
```

Comment: whats the error , post your error console

Comment: Hussain Akhtar Wahid 'Ghouri' i dont have any error in my console.Am getting the from and subject clearly but doesnt get the content of my mails

Comment: Litmus has a free plugin for Chrome/Gmail called [Scope](https://litmus.com/scope/). You can inspect the code there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your issue:

[Message#getContent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/Part.html#getContent%28%29)

So once you have the object i.e. `Object content = message.getContent()` you should do an instance check to see if it's either a `String` or `Multipart` class. I.e.

```
Object content = message.getContent()
if ( content instanceof String )
{
    String text = (String) content;
    // Do things
}
else if ( content instanceof Multipart ) 
{
    Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) content;
    // Do things
}
```

Comment: Zyn thanks but actually i didnt get it actually..
can u please alter my code and give..

Comment: Actually, try the following: instead of `System.out.println(message.getContent());` try `message.writeTo( System.out );`. I am unable to test as of this moment.